# Compute number of combinations

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, card-games

I got really stuck with this task:

> Nine of ten cards, among which there is an ace of hearts, are
>   distributed to three players so that the first one receives 3, the
>   second - 4, and the third - 2 cards. How many cards combinations exist,
>   where an ace of hearts gets to a third player?

I think that number of combinations formula is $c_{9}^{1} * c_{3}^{1} * c_{2}^{1} = 6$

Am I right? I will be so grateful for your help!)

Comment: What does your $c_a^b$ mean?

Comment: As well as that, are all the cards distinct?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel could it be OP means $$c_n^k = \binom{n}{k}?$$

Comment: The ace of hearts is among those nine cards or among those ten cards? I think among those ten, but just to be sure?

Comment: @TStancek of course, among them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give the ace of hearts to the third player first. Then allocate the rest of the hands:

- The third player gets a second card to complete their hand in $\binom91=9$ ways, leaving $8$ cards
- The second player gets their hand in $\binom84=70$ ways, leaving $4$ cards
- The first player gets their hand in $\binom43=4$ ways

Thus there are $9\times70\times4=2520$ ways to distribute the cards.

Comment: Is it solution for combinations, where an ace of hearts gets to a third player? Because it looks like all ways to distribute the cards among 3 players

Comment: @LordofPrograms Yes, combinations.

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot)